# Sharepoint 2013 .NET CSOM CamlQuery Join

Tags: .net, sharepoint, join, caml, csom

I am unable to create a working query with join in my .net csom application. I was using this article:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff798388.aspx

here is my code:

```
 ClientContext context = new ClientContext(url);
 Web web = context.Web;
 var list = web.Lists.GetByTitle("Esemény");

 CamlQuery cq = new CamlQuery();
 cq.ViewXml= @"<View>
                   <ViewFields>
                       <FieldRef Name='Title' />
                   </ViewFields>
                   <ProjectedFields>
                       <Field Name='PartnerLookupTitle' Type='Lookup' List='PartnerLookup' ShowField='Title' />
                   </ProjectedFields>
                   <Joins>
                       <Join Type='LEFT' ListAlias='PartnerLookup'>
                           <Eq>
                               <FieldRef Name='Partner' RefType='ID' />
                               <FieldRef List='Partner' Name='ID' />
                           </Eq>
                       </Join>
                   </Joins>
               </View>";

ListItemCollection lista =  list.GetItems(cq);
context.Load(lista);
context.ExecuteQuery();
```

I get an exception from the server:
"Value does not fall within the expected range."

If I remove the the ProjectedFields and Joins part of the CAML query it works:(

Comment: Your question is a good one (+1 for you). I suggest you ask for help also on a sister site of Stack Overflow: [Sharepoint](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com).

Comment: @user2791953 Did you ever solve this?

Comment: At first sight: `<FieldRef List='Partner' Name='ID' />` should be `<FieldRef List='PartnerLookup' Name='ID' />`.

Answer (score 0):

Joins are not common used when doing CAML SPQuery. As a workaround the data from the two lists may be pulled separately in two

`List<SpListItem>`

objects for examle and then you can do in-memory join between the two lists.

Comment: Come on... I use these joins every day.

Answer (score -1):

This error occurs due to malformed CAML query, in particular:

- value for `ListAlias` attribute of `Join` element should contain List name
- value for `List` attribute of `Field` element should contain List name

---

The following method demonstrates how to construct query for [List Joins and Projections](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee539975(v=office.14).aspx):

```
public static CamlQuery CreateJoinQuery(string joinListTitle,string joinFieldName,string[] viewdFields,string[] projectedFields)
{
        var qry = new CamlQuery();
        qry.ViewXml = @"<View>
               <ViewFields>";
        foreach(var f in viewdFields) {
            qry.ViewXml+= string.Format("<FieldRef Name='{0}' />",f);
        }
        foreach(var f in projectedFields) {
            qry.ViewXml+= string.Format("<FieldRef Name='{0}{1}' />",joinListTitle,f);
        }
        qry.ViewXml+= @"</ViewFields>
               <ProjectedFields>";
        foreach(var f in projectedFields){
            qry.ViewXml+= string.Format("<Field Name='{0}{1}' Type='Lookup' List='{0}' ShowField='{1}' />",joinListTitle,f);
        }
         qry.ViewXml+= string.Format(@"</ProjectedFields>
               <Joins>
                   <Join Type='LEFT' ListAlias='{0}'>
                       <Eq>
                           <FieldRef Name='{1}' RefType='ID' />
                           <FieldRef List='{0}' Name='ID' />
                       </Eq>
                   </Join>
               </Joins>
           </View>",joinListTitle,joinFieldName);
         return qry;
}
```

Assume the following lists:

- `Contacts` - contains Country lookup field (target list: Countries)
- `Countries`

Then the following example demonstrates how to retrieve list items from both lists.

**Usage**

```
var listTitle = "Contacts";
var joinListTitle = "Countries"; 
var joinFieldName = "Country";
var projectedFields = new []{"ID","Title"};
var viewFields = new[] { "Title" };

using (var ctx = new ClientContext(webUri))
{
      var list = ctx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(listTitle);
      var qry = CreateJoinQuery(joinListTitle,joinFieldName,viewFields,projectedFields);
      var items = list.GetItems(qry);
      ctx.Load(items);
      ctx.ExecuteQuery();
}
```